# Where do serialport names come from?

Tags: serial

I'm currently writing a tool that automatically detects connected arduinos and provides a one-button solution for flashing new firmware.
I've got a couple of arduinos at home (Diecimilla, Uno R3 SMD and some nanos from china) and each type presents with a different serial port name.

**Questions**

- Can someone explain where these port names come from?
- Can I assume that `/dev/cu.usbserial-A9UPDRZB` is, atleast in most cases, an arduino nano?
- Are there other ways to identify the type of the board?
- Is the name of the serial port some kind of hash generated from informations retrieved from the device?

Comment: They come from your OS.

Comment: You might get a lot of useful information from this question https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/in-linux-how-to-identify-multiple-arduinos-connected-over-usb

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really answer my questions.

Comment: It does tell you where you can find them though.

Comment: It doesn't. It tells me where to get more information about the connected hardware. But that doesn't answer the questions about how the names are generated.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That answer does tell you how to make linux create names you want, or, if you prefer, to invoke programs when you plug in specific devices. You might want to indicate which OS you want to use, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assume anything about serial port names. It's a choice of the operating system, and even if you find the algorithm, there's no guarantee it won't change in the future.

As a reference implementation, the [Arduino IDE 1.5.x](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software#toc3) uses VID (Vendor ID) and PID (Product ID) to identify a board.

Because accessing such information depends on the underlying operating system, the IDE uses three strategies: on windows, it runs a program called ListComPorts.exe, on macosx it uses CLI tool `/usr/sbin/system_profiler`, on linux CLI tool `udevadm`