# Risks of ftdi_eeprom? - TX always high after flashing

Tags: arduino-nano, ftdi

I flashed an Arduino Nano compatible with ftdi_eeprom and the following config:

```
vendor_id=0x0403    # Vendor ID
product_id=0x6001   # Product ID

max_power=0     # Max. power consumption: value * 2 mA. Use 0 if self_powered = true.

###########
# Strings #
########### 
manufacturer="FTDI"     # Manufacturer
product="Arduino Nano"  # Product
serial="arduino_1"      # Serial

###########
# Options #
###########
self_powered=false  # Turn this off for bus powered
remote_wakeup=false # Turn this on for remote wakeup feature
use_serial=true     # Use the serial number string

# Normally out don't have to change one of these flags
BM_type_chip=true       # Newer chips are all BM type
in_is_isochronous=false     # In Endpoint is Isochronous
out_is_isochronous=false    # Out Endpoint is Isochronous
suspend_pull_downs=false    # Enable suspend pull downs for lower power
change_usb_version=false    # Change USB Version
usb_version=0x0200      # Only used when change_usb_version is enabled

########
# Misc #
########

filename="eeprom.new"   # Filename, leave empty to skip file writing
```

My corresponfing `udev` rules work and I get `/dev/arduino_1` after connecting.

However. After the flash, everything seems to work, But: The TX-LED is constantly on. Even, when the device is not sending. Why?

**Update & solution**

First, I removed this line, because it threw warning messages (outdated)

```
# BM_type_chip=true         # Newer chips are all BM type
```

Then I studied the [schematics](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoNano30Schematic.pdf) of the Nano and figured out, that `RX` and `TX`  LEDs are indeed connected to `CBUS0` and `CBUS1`. So, I added two lines to my config

```
  cbus0=RXLED
  cbus1=TXLED
```

Which had the effect, that now both `RX` and `TX` where constantly on. So, I finally read the [manual](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/FT232R_v104.pdf) which says on page 11, that the commands in question need a trailing `#`. I updated my config again:

```
cbus0=RXLED#
cbus1=TXLED#
```

**Extra:**

Indeed, I had to install `ftdi_eeprom` to get the job done

```
 apt-get remove ftdi-eeprom
 apt-get install swig libusb-1.0-0-dev libconfuse-dev doxygen
 git clone https://github.com/legege/libftdi.git
 cd libftdi.git
 cmake .
 make 
 make install
 ftdi_eeprom/ftdi_eeprom --flash-eeprom myconfig.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ftdi_eeprom` utility re-writes the entire EEPROM, not just the selected bits you have chosen.  That includes the "CBUS" pin configurations.

You need to check on the Nano's schematic which LED is connected to which `CBUSx` pin on the FTDI and set it accordingly.  You do that in your config using:

```
cbus0=TXLED
cbus1=RXLED
```

for example.

Possible settings for the CBUS pins are:

- TXDEN
- PWREN
- RXLED
- TXLED
- TXRXLED
- SLEEP
- CLK48
- CLK24
- CLK12
- CLK6
- IO_MODE
- BITBANG_WR
- BITBANG_RD
- SPECIAL

Except CBUS4 which only has the functions:

- TXDEN
- PWRON
- RXLED
- TXLED
- TX_RX_LED
- SLEEP
- CLK48
- CLK24
- CLK12
- CLK6

There is a chance that your pre-packages version of `ftdi_eeprom` doesn't support those settings, so you will need to download and compile the latest version from source from here: https://github.com/legege/libftdi

Also during testing I accidentally changed the VID of one of my boards thus rendering it unresponsive.  I did that by omitting the `0x` from the VID and PID numbers.  Extreme care should be exercised using thin utility.  I have submitted a patch to allow the specification of a default VID for recovery from such situations.

Comment: I'll try that today and give a reply. Thanks very much so far