# Can I specify custom port names in the Arduino IDE on Linux?

Tags: arduino-ide, linux

On Linux, if you have more than one USB TTY device, the USB port name (`/dev/ttyUSBx`) changes every time one is plugged in, and there's no easy way to know the new name without going and looking through dmesg.  [It's trivial to set up a udev rule that creates a custom symlink](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/) so that my Arduino's FTDI can always be accessed through e.g., `/dev/ttyArduino`, and this is the standard procedure for persistent access to USB devices.

However, I can't make the IDE accept anything other than the `/dev/ttyUSBx` names.  Even directly editing `preferences.txt` is ignored.

Is there any way to instruct the IDE to use custom port names in order to access the Arduino through a symlink or other persistent name?

Comment: I am not aware of a way in the Arduino IDE, but you can in [UECIDE](http://uecide.org).

Comment: Look here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/in-linux-how-to-identify-multiple-arduinos-connected-over-usb/22323#22323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a device name of form ttyUSBnn, where nn is fairly large.  For example, in /dev you could say

```
sudo ln -s ttyUSB1 ttyUSB77
```

Then, `ttyUSB77` shows up in the IDE's ports list and can be selected.

(I don't know how to set up that link using the `udev` system, but imagine it can be done.)

Comment: Excellent hack, and it does work. Thanks.  If nobody answers with an IDE configuration answer in a few days I'll accept this.

Comment: This is also very dynamic and will not do what you've asked for

Comment: Obviously this is a one-off hack and doesn't work on the next plug-in, but doing it from udev appears to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Think the other way.

If your device has a port name, that is not supported by the IDE, you can create an additional (static) symlink `/dev/USBx` that you can identify and select in the arduino IDE.

And yes, it is quite easy to [make all of your arduinos unique](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/in-linux-how-to-identify-multiple-arduinos-connected-over-usb/22323#22323) to udev.

Comment: Thanks!   Your link on how to flash a new serial number to an FTDI chip is very cool.  Unfortunately, there's nothing similar for the (all-too-common) CH340 and PL2303 chips -- they have no onboard storage.